# Rename dll using OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, dll, rename, openfiledialog

I'm stuck with my program in C#. So the user has to press a button to create a random string (working fine) he can then chose to click on the other button. this one opens a `FileDialog` and let him chose a dll file he wants to rename into the random string. I can't get it working. it says my dll is already running in another process (which is not). Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
private void btnEncrypt_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sets a random string to txtEncrypt.text
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog MyOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    //filedialog
    MyOpenFileDialog.Filter = "dll files (*.dll) |*.dll";//filter
    MyOpenFileDialog.Title = "Chose the dll file";
    MyOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Desktop";
    MyOpenFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    MyOpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    //if ok
    if (MyOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        strPath = MyOpenFileDialog.FileName;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strPath);

        System.IO.File.Move(strPath,
            "C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Desktop\\" + txtEncrypt.Text + ".dll");
    }
    else //cancel
    {
        strPath = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `wich is not` Do you think NET and the OS are lying to you?  Nothinkg good can come of letting users rename DLLs anyway.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Yes it is.  _You_ are using it by creating a `StreamReader` it. What's the point of the `StreamReader` anyway?

Comment: Renaming .dlls will essentially orphan them.  Plus **kernel32.dll** will get a tad grumpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your StreamReader is opening the file so it can't be moved. That line doesn't appear to be doing anything anyway so you can probably remove it. Ideally replace it with

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(strPath))
{
    System.IO.File.Move(strPath, "C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Desktop\\" + txtEncrypt.Text + ".dll");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the initialization of the streem reader line or move it next to the rename line but don't forget to pass the new name